# Asus N53 RT5592 on Ubunti 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, asus

I cannot get the system to use the wireless card. As far as I can tell, it acknowledges that the thing is plugged in, and even what it is.

[image]

However, it apparently says disabled.

The only driver I could get to install without failing was this one:

https://github.com/kuttor/Asus-N53-PCU-RT5592STA-Driver-for-Linux-Kernel-4.6-Ubuntu-16.10

And I'm assuming it's installed correctly, but it's not working

Comment: Please avoid screen-shots of plain text as it is a burden for our servers. Instead you can copy terminal-output and paste it into the question, then use code-tags like`<pre>text</pre>. This way text is much better to read too.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off `secure boot` in your BIOS. Ubuntu won't load unsigned kernel drivers.

Comment: I checked, Secure boot is indeed disabled.

Comment: Show me the `terminal` output of `dkms status` and `uname -r`. Please edit into your question, not in the comments please.

Comment: What happens if you issue `sudo ifconfig ra0 up` (replacing ra0 with the correct device name)? Does that make it work?

Answer (score 1):

this is actually my Github account... and I just confirmed the driver is working on Linux 4.11.2.

TO get it to work I did the make clean, make, make install.

Then,

1. sudo ip link set "name of the Wifi" down
2. sudo ip link set "name of the Wifi" up
3. sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager